# Python- find the source creating the GC overhead

Tags: python, apache-spark, garbage-collection

I have a pyspark code which consistently gives me gc overhead issues. While I can avoid this by bumping up the heap limit but I would still like to understand what part of my code is creating this issue.

So is there a way I can profile my code like cProfile does for run times, for garbage collection. Specifically, I am looking to see if there are circular references and memory leaks in my code.

Comment: What exactly are "gc overhead issues"? Are you talking about the GC in CPython, or the JVM GC? What symptom do you have, and what have you measured that tells you that symptom is caused by something related to the GC?

Comment: I think this is more related to Spark, rather than python, so I'll suggest adding that tag. As far as I know, there exist several [older posts](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/05/28/tuning-java-garbage-collection-for-spark-applications.html) that go into a little more detail about garbage collection. A lot has changed since then, maybe the Spark community can help you out more!

Comment: @abarnert, So the script basically takes in data and fits models with different parameters. In doing so, I keep runninng into `GC overhead limit exceeded`. I read a little bit on the issue. I know I can change the JVM heap size but I want to know what if there are potential issues with my code.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you keep a watch on Spark lineage as you perform transformations.

```
df.explain(extended=True)
```

Also, you should keep breaking as it grows. You can break it by

```
df= df.checkpoint(eager=True)
```

Check if this solution helps